# Проблема в движке Boxcode - доска объявлений

Tags: php, javascript, html

Проблема заключается в том что я пытался добавить валюту (тенге).
Чтобы это сделать понадобилось внести её в файлы:

В файле `config.php` добавил валюту

```
//курсы валют

$init_currency = array(
"kzt" => array("Казахстанский тенге","тенг. "),
"rub" => array("Российский Рубль","руб. "),
"usd" => array("Американский Доллар","дол. "),
"uah" => array("Украинская Гривна","грн. "),
"eur" => array("Европейский Евро","евро"),
);
$init_base_currency = "kzt";
```

Далее сделал в файле настроек валюты в папке `config_save /initcurrency.php`

```
$init_base_currency = "kzt";
$init_use_currency = array("kzt","rub","usd","eur");
$init_course_currency = array("kzt" => 1,
"rub" => 1,
"usd" => 0.033,
"uah" => 0.3,
"eur" => 0.025);
```

Еще добавил данные об валютах в массив настроек `$masConfig` в файле `config_main.php` эти строчки:

```
define('init_currency','rub,usd,eur,byr');
$masConfig['init_currency'] = 'rub,usd,eur,byr';
define('init_base_currency','rub');
$masConfig['init_base_currency'] = 'rub';
define('data_base_currency','rub');
$masConfig['data_base_currency'] = 'rub';
define('init_use_currency','rub,usd,eur,byr');
$masConfig['init_use_currency'] = 'rub,usd,eur,byr';
define('init_course_currency','rub');
$masConfig['init_course_currency'] = 'rub => 1';
```

валюта появилась на сайте но когда выбираешь тенге выходит сообщение ( не все поля введены) хотя все поля введены ПРОВЕРЕННОЕ но если выбрать другую валюту к примеру рубль либо доллар то объявление появляется без проблем. Прошу помочь потому что тех поддержка не может мне помочь в это полагаюсь на вас добрые люди.

[image: screenshot]